# How can i check a radio button?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

i have this code :

```
 <input type="radio" name="condition-shorturl-opt" value="Et" id="condition-and-shorturl" >
 <label for='condition-and-shorturl'>ON</label>
 <input type="radio" name="condition-shorturl-opt" value="Ou" id="condition-or-shorturl">
 <label for='condition-or-shorturl'>OFF</label>
```

i was wondering how i can check with jquery one of the input radio so i tried this code:

```
    $('#condition-and-shorturl').attr( "checked", true );
    $('#condition-and-shorturl').attr( "checked", "checked" ); 
    $('#condition-and-shorturl').attr('checked', 'checked' );  
    $('#condition-and-shorturl').prop( "checked", true );
    $('#condition-and-shorturl').prop( "checked", "checked" );
    $('#condition-and-shorturl').prop('checked', 'checked' );
```

None of them works for me any help please?

Comment: Both of your input tags are not closed, this may be a source of some problems.

Comment: Do you added jquery file? Do you have any error in console?

Comment: @Mohammad no console error

Answer (score 0):

```js
const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");

radioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton){
  radioButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("I know someone just click on ones button,WHO!");
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="condition-shorturl-opt" value="Et" id="condition-and-shorturl" >
 <label for='condition-and-shorturl'>ON</label>
<input type="radio" name="condition-shorturl-opt" value="Ou" id="condition-or-shorturl">
<label for='condition-or-shorturl'>OFF</label>
```

And also you are missing the `"` at line 3 from the HTML code

Comment: thanks for response but  actually this is not what i want , i need just that my input get checked .

Comment: `radioButton.checked = true`

Answer (score 0):

You can move around the problem and simply use `.trigger()` instead of `attr` or `prop`, Something like this:

```js
$( "#condition-and-shorturl" ).trigger( "click" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="condition-shorturl-opt" value="Et" id="condition-and-shorturl" >
<label for='condition-and-shorturl'>ON</label>
<input type="radio" name="condition-shorturl-opt" value="Ou" id="condition-or-shorturl">
<label for='condition-or-shorturl'>OFF</label>
```